# TypeError - Cannot read property 'use' of undefined when using i18next

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a project with the following dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "express-rest-i18n": "^1.0.1",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
    "i18next": "^21.6.14",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.0",
    "i18next-http-middleware": "^3.2.0",
    "joi": "^17.4.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.4",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
```

my i18n configuration code is as following:

```
const i18next = require("i18next").default;
const Backend = require("i18next-http-backend").default;
const i18nextMiddleware = require("i18next-http-middleware");

i18next
  .use(Backend)
  .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: __dirname + `/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`,
    },
    fallbackLng: "en",
    preload: ["en"],
  });

module.exports = { i18next };
```

My app code is as following:

```
const { i18next } = require("../locales/i18n");
const messages = require("../locales/en/translation.json");
const i18nextMiddleware = require("i18next-http-middleware");

require("express-async-errors");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  const response = req.t("greeting");
  res.status(200);
  res.send(response);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
module.exports = app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`)
);
```

When I start the application by running npm start, I receive the error: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined*

This error exist because Backend in the configuration file is undefined.
I have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-http-middleware as a resource.

Why am I receiving this error and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you accessing .default?

Just import like this:

```
const i18next = require("i18next");
const Backend = require("i18next-http-backend");
```

Comment: it is working as you said, but I'm getting an two errors in my editor. One at i18next in the middleware handle method and the other one at i18next.use(Backend )

Answer (score 0):

Read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript

In your `tsconfig.json`, make sure to add:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
  },
}
```